# How to decrypt string encrypted by openssl enc -a -e -aes-256-cbc in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, encryption

For decrypt and encrypt a string is used:

```
openssl enc -a -e -aes-256-cbc -K decryptKeyWitch64characters -iv initVectorHas32chars
openssl enc -a -d -aes-256-cbc -K decryptKeyWitch64characters -iv initVectorHas32chars
```

although key has 64 chars and iv has 32 chars above commands working well.

I need to wrote decrypt part in kotlin for android, so:

```
private fun decryptText(text: String?, secret: String?, iv: String?): String? {
    text ?: return null
    secret ?: return null
    iv ?: return null

    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding")
    val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(secret.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), "AES")

    val array: ByteArray = Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT)
    val encrypted: ByteArray = array.copyOfRange(0, array.size)
    cipher.init(
        Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
        secretKeySpec,
        IvParameterSpec(iv.toByteArray())
    )
    return try {
        String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted)).trim()
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        Timber.e(e)
        return null
    }
}
```

but I get error: `InvalidKeyException: Unsupported key size: 64 bytes`
So I tried diffrent paddings:

OAEPPadding:

```
NoSuchAlgorithmException: No provider found for AES/CBC/OAEPPadding
```

PKCS1Padding

```
NoSuchAlgorithmException: No provider found for AES/CBC/PKCS1Padding
```

PKCS5Padding:

```
InvalidKeyException: Unsupported key size: 64 bytes
```

SSL3Padding:

```
NoSuchAlgorithmException: No provider found for AES/CBC/SSL3Padding
```

ISO10126Padding

```
InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: IV must be 16 bytes long
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: Key and IV are hex encoded in the OpenSSL statement. Therefore the corresponding hex decoding is missing in the Kotlin code. The PKCS7 padding is correct.

Comment: That is because an ``IV`` must be 16 bytes long and  the size of ``key`` depends on the encoding you're using. For ``AES-128``, the ``key`` must be ``16`` bytes long, ``24`` bytes long for ``AES-192`` and ``32`` bytes long for ``AES-256``.

Comment: @Topaco that was it! thx! :)